# Augmenting data structure without wasting memory

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, binary-search-tree

I have a class `Tree` that I'd like to augment into more specialized data structures, such as `Order_tree` and `Interval_tree`. These augmentations require additions to the `Node`, such as size information, and minor alterations to some algorithms.

I'd like to know the best way to implement augmentations in C++ in terms of performance, readability, and maintainability. The trees should not be used in a polymorphic manner. What I've attempted so far is publicly inheriting `Tree`, and then overloading the base methods. (I apologize for being a beginner at object oriented programming)

```
template <typename T>
class Tree {
protected:
    enum class Color : char {BLACK = 0, RED = 1};

    struct Node {
        T key;
        Node *parent, *left, *right;
        Color color;
        Node() : color{Color::BLACK} {} // sentinel construction
        Node(T val, Color col = Color::RED) : key{val}, parent{nil}, left{nil}, right{nil}, color{col} {}
    };
    using NP = typename Tree::Node*;

    NP root {nil};
    // nil sentinel
    static NP nil;

    // core utility algorithms...

};

template <typename T>
typename Tree<T>::NP Tree<T>::nil {new Node{}};
```

Order tree

```
template <typename T>
class Order_tree : public Tree<T> {
    using Color = typename Tree<T>::Color;
    using Tree<T>::Tree;    // inherit constructors
    struct Order_node {
        T key;
        Order_node *parent, *left, *right;
        size_t size;    // # of descendent nodes including itself = left->size + right->size + 1
        Color color;
        Order_node() : size{0}, color{Color::BLACK} {}  // sentinel construction
        Order_node(T val, Color col = Color::RED) : key{val}, parent{nil}, left{nil}, right{nil}, size{1}, color{col} {}
    };
    using NP = typename Order_tree::Order_node*;
    NP root {nil};
    static NP nil;

    // overloading on only the methods that need changing
};

template <typename T>
typename Order_tree<T>::NP Order_tree<T>::nil {new Order_node{}};
```

However, this doesn't behave properly since now I have 2 roots and 2 nils, with all the base methods working on the base root and with `Tree<T>::NP` rather than `Order_tree::NP` so the `Order_node`'s size attribute cannot be used.

One way is to copy-paste the code, which is highly unmaintainable. Another way I think is to template Tree on T as well as NP, so that `Order_tree` is an alias `using Order_tree = Tree<Order_node>` and specialize tree on the node.

Comment: It makes more sense to have the `T` template parameter for your various `tree` classes be the structure they should store in each node, including what you're currently considering the `value` and the "augmentation" data.  If you want a particular part of the `T` data type to act as key, you can require that the field be called `key`, that there be a `typedef` for `key_type;` or whatever else supports your intended client usage; or alternatively you can have a second template parameter specifically for the key, much as is done for `std::map`.

Comment: Would that be an extra level of indirection though (in terms of readability and performance)? (to access key you'd have to say `node->data->key` assuming node's payload is `T data` where data as you suggested would be a struct holding at least a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found the best way to achieve what I want by:

- template Tree on Node type
- make nil a static element of each Node type
- move some private methods that work on nodes with no reliance on
  root out to be normal functions templated on Node
- make the functions that might be changed virtual
- augment Tree by publicly
  inheriting from it and overriding necessary virtual functions
- use the
  base Tree's root (hold no data in the derived class)

What it looks like now: 
**tree.h**

```
namespace sal {

// utilities with no dependence on root, outside of class now
template <typename Node>
Node* tree_find(Node* start, typename Node::key_type key) {
    while (start != Node::nil && start->key != key) {
        if (key < start->key) start = start->left;
        else start = start->right;
    }
    return start;
}
// more of them...

template <typename Node>
class Tree {
protected:
    using NP = Node*;
    using T = typename Node::key_type;

    // nil is static member of each Node type now
    NP root {Node::nil};

    // virtual methods that could be changed by augmentation
    virtual void rotate_left(NP node);
    virtual void rotate_right(NP node);
    virtual void tree_insert(NP start, NP node);
    virtual void rb_delete(NP node);

    // non-virtual methods that are never overridden
    void rb_insert_fixup(NP node);
    void rb_delete_fixup(NP successor);
    void rb_insert(NP node);  // just a call to tree_insert and rb_insert_fixup
    void transplant(NP old, NP moved);
public:
    virtual ~Tree();  // does all the clean up so its derived classes don't have to
    // interface...
};

template <typename T>
struct Basic_node {
    static Basic_node* nil;

    using key_type = T;
    T key;
    Basic_node *parent, *left, *right;
    Color color;
    Basic_node() : color{Color::BLACK} {}   // sentinel construction
    Basic_node(T val) : key{val}, parent{nil}, left{nil}, right{nil}, color{Color::RED} {}
};

template <typename T>
using Basic_tree = Tree<Basic_node<T>>;

template <typename T>
Basic_node<T>* Basic_node<T>::nil {new Basic_node{}};

}
```

**order_tree.h**

```
#include "tree.h"

namespace sal {

template <typename Node>
class Order_augment : public Tree<Node> {

    using NP = Node*;
    using T = typename Node::key_type;
    using Tree<Node>::root;

    // no need to redefine shared core functions
    using Tree<Node>::rb_insert;
    using Tree<Node>::transplant;
    using Tree<Node>::rb_insert_fixup;
    using Tree<Node>::rb_delete_fixup;

    // order statistics operations
    NP os_select(NP start, size_t rank) const;
    size_t os_rank(NP node) const;

    // modification of rb operations to maintain augmentation
    virtual void tree_insert(NP start, NP node) override;
    virtual void rb_delete(NP node) override;
    virtual void rotate_left(NP node) override;
    virtual void rotate_right(NP node) override;
public:
    // augmented interface
};

template <typename T>
struct Order_node {
    static Order_node* nil;

    using key_type = T;
    T key;
    Order_node *parent, *left, *right;
    size_t size;    // # of descendent nodes including itself = left->size + right->size + 1
    Color color;
    Order_node() : size{0}, color{Color::BLACK} {}  // sentinel construction
    Order_node(T val) : key{val}, parent{nil}, left{nil}, right{nil}, size{1}, color{Color::RED} {}
};

template <typename T>
Order_node<T>* Order_node<T>::nil {new Order_node{}};

template <typename T>
using Order_tree = Order_augment<Order_node<T>>;

}
```

The result is that the file size holding the augmented data structures are now about 1/3 as large, and the code duplication is removed entirely! Which means any changes to improve the core methods can be localized to only tree.h and its effect will be felt in all augmented trees as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in having "general tree of all trees", it seems the problem is not in tree but in Node. You need some special cases of nodes so why not to generalize them too? For example:

```
 template <typename T>
class Tree {
protected:
    struct BaseNode {
    //all code you really can generalize here 
    };

    struct Node : public BaseNode {
    //You need Node here only if you want your base Tree class to be ready to use.
    //If you want to use only its derives such as Order_tree,
    //you create special nodes kinds only there
    };

    // core utility algorithms...

BaseNode * root; //Only one root node, there is no need in duplication! 
                 //You can instantiate it as root = new OrderTreeNode or root = new SpecialTreeNode in any derives.

};
```

However the price for Node virtual function calls is rather big. So you need to understand clearly - do you need generalization and not duplication of code or do you need perfomance.

Comment: I see, so there is no compromise here? I think the functionality I'm asking for is reasonable - statically bind all the methods of the `Tree` class to work on other types of `Node`s, and override the ones I explicitly change.

Comment: You can do it by some template traits, but the code would be huge and also much duplicated. This point is the main reason I personally going to switch from C++ to Rust, the latter has clear and simple trait mechanism in language itself.