# Static class variable in template class considered template

Tags: c++, templates, static-members, null, sentinel

I have a static variable, `nil`, which acts as a sentinel for `template <typename Node> Tree`. I am [augmenting my trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478387/augmenting-data-structure-without-wasting-memory/) by specializing on the `Node` type. However, I'm having trouble constructing the nils.

**Nil as static member of Tree**

Inside `tree.h`

```
template <typename Node>
class Tree {
    using NP = Node*;
    using T = typename Node::key_type;

    NP root {nil};
    // nil sentinel
    static NP nil;

    // core utilities
    const static NP get_nil() {
        return nil;
    }
};

enum class Color : char {BLACK = 0, RED = 1};

template <typename T>
struct Basic_node {
        using key_type = T;
        T key;
        Basic_node *parent, *left, *right;
        Color color;
        Basic_node() : color{Color::BLACK} {}   // sentinel construction
        Basic_node(T val, Color col = Color::RED) : 
            key{val}, 
            parent{Tree<Basic_node>::get_nil()}, 
            left{Tree<Basic_node>::get_nil()}, 
            right{Tree<Basic_node>::get_nil()}, 
            color{col} {}
};

template <typename T>
using Basic_tree = Tree<Basic_node<T>>;

template <typename T>
typename Basic_tree<T>::NP Basic_tree<T>::nil {new Basic_node<T>};
// alternatively
template <typename T>
Basic_node<T>* Basic_tree<T>::nil {new Basic_node{}};
```

The error 
`template definition of non-template 'typename sal::Basic_tree<T>::NP sal::Tree<sal::Basic_node<T> >::nil'` 
occurs in the last two lines.

I want the same nil to be used for all trees using `Basic_node` with every T type.

**Nil as static member of Node**

I then tried making nil a static member of `Basic_node`. This way the nodes don't depend on the tree (that `parent{Tree<Basic_node>::get_nil()}` is really nasty) and is more natural.

```
template <typename T>
struct Basic_node {
        static Basic_node* nil;

        using key_type = T;
        T key;
        Basic_node *parent, *left, *right;
        Color color;
        Basic_node() : color{Color::BLACK} {}   // sentinel construction
        Basic_node(T val, Color col = Color::RED) : key{val}, parent{nil}, left{nil}, right{nil}, color{col} {}
};
template <typename T>
Basic_node<T>* Basic_node<T>::nil {new Basic_node{}};

// inside Tree
using Node::nil;
```

The new error is `type 'sal::Basic_node<int>' is not a base type for type 'sal::Tree<sal::Basic_node<int> >'` meaning I'm abusing `using` as it assumes I'm referring to a hierarchy. What I want to mean here is to use `Node::nil` when I refer to `nil` in the rest of Tree.

(**Note that my last approach worked**, it's just that I have to refer to Node::nil every time; also, I'm curious if there's any extra indirection introduced by Node::nil).

Comment: This looks like a convoluted and overly complicated design. Why don't you simply use `nullptr`? Is there any place where the actual type matters?

Comment: You can't use the same type of pointer because the template arguments are indeed different, and this means that the nodes are actually of different types. As Walter suggests, `nullptr` is compatible with any pointer type.

Comment: Sentinels are actually incredibly useful in simplifying the design since it removes a lot of null checks. Since the base tree is a RB tree, the leaves(nils) should all be coloured black. This guarantees that all nodes will have a colour. If they were nullptr, then you'd have to check if they were null, and only check the colour after making sure they weren't null.

Comment: @LemonPi At the end of the day the answer is that if the node is a template then you can't have a "global" sentinel because the nodes are all of different types. You *could* have a global value of some random type, where that type has a template implicit conversion to a nil node of any type.